# Переход словосочетания в сложное слово

Tags: словосочетания

Можно ли обозначить человека отвязного и беспечного сложным словом, состоящим из глагола и существительного, соединённых дефисом?

Пример: "гуляй-душа".

Answer (score 1):

Первое, что приходит на ум, -- "сорви-голова".  Но дефис в этом слове, как правило, опускают и пишут просто "сорвиголова". (Хотя я встречал и написание через дефис.)

Подобное словообразование может оказаться применимо не только к человеку, но и к топониму. Я имею в виду Гуляй-Поле. Интересно, что ещё несколько десятилетий назад дефис в этом слове присутствовал (см "Думу про Опанаса"). Но впоследствии он был утрачен, и на сегодняшний день написание без дефиса, "Гуляйполе", уже стало официальным.